# What is the length of the generated android Firebase token?

Tags: android, firebase

I am looking for the length of the firebase token that is generated in android. I also would like to know if this length is fixed on android platform and other platforms.(ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/custom.html

> The token payload can contain any data of your choosing with the
>   restriction that it must contain a uid key that is a string of less
>   than 256 characters. The generated token's total payload must also be
>   less than 1024 characters.